# How to get bluetooth serial port tx/rx buffers status?

Tags: networking, wireless, bash, bluetooth, serial-port

The problem comes from that I have to send data via bluetooth serial port from a tiny robot to my laptop at baudrate 115200, robot sends 32-bytes packet every 10ms (100 times per second). Transmission works only a few seconds, and then `cat` shows nothing. When I decrease frequency to 10 times per second it works smoothly. I suppose that bluetooth serial port rx buffer overflows.

Getting status of serial ports (`ttyS*`) via terminal is simple:

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
```

Then it shows `serinfo` with list of all uarts and info about status and buffers. When I call

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/drivers
```

I can see that `rfcomm` drivers are available:

```
rfcomm   /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
```

And, of course, reading data coming from paired bluetooth device (e.g. via `cat` or pipe) is not a problem.

The question is: how to get status of rfcomm serial ports (e.g. Blueotooth SPP devices), especially amount of data in rx/tx buffers? Is this information available somewhere in the `/proc` directory like for `ttyS*` or could I use totally different way?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. ;-) That is so development-related that I'm afraid you'll be better off asking that at http://stackoverflow.com a sister site to Ask Ubuntu...  :(

Comment: Heh, actually I've asked very similar question on stackoverflow. I hadn't got helpful answers but the same suggestion - to ask on another stack site concerning linux related problems :D